# Using back slash in a variable

Tags: python

Why do I see two back slashes when I type variable name on python shell ?

```
>>> print '6\\3=2'
6\3=2           ==> Correctly prints back slash
>>> var1='6\\3=2'
>>> print(var1)
6\3=2          ==> Correctly prints back slash
>>> var1
'6\\3=2'       ==> Why do I see two back slashes here ? Instead of just one ? 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The output in the python shell is the string representation. It is printed in the same way, as one would type it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> The str() function is meant to return representations of values which
>   are fairly human-readable, while repr() is meant to generate
>   representations which can be read by the interpreter (or will force a
>   SyntaxError if there is no equivalent syntax)

`print()` calls `__str__()` on the object, while putting the var `var1` in the console just calls the objects internal representation `__repr__()`.

```
>>> print(var1.__str__())
6\2=1
>>> print(var1.__repr__())
'6\\2=1'
```